# Cross platform mobile application with photo editing and push notification - suggestion

Tags: android, ios, cordova

We are developing a mobile dating application which includes the following features:

1. Manage Photos:

   - Add/Delete
   - Able To Crop Photo
   - Reduce File Size
   - Auto Set Dimensions Of Photos Before Uploading To Server
2. Push notifications

If our target platforms are iOS and Android, could we achieve the above tasks using phonegap or similar cross-platform development apps?

If not, please suggest if there is an alternate way other than native development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, the tasks you described could be done using Phonegap with a help of an external JS library (example : pixastic) that can help you achieve some actions like cropping, resizing, etc.

But, the problem with Phonegap is that it is related to the browser's performance. As you know, the most used android versions are 2.3 and 2.2 . Their built-in browsers (used by Phonegap) can have some difficulties to load corretly some pages or render them as quick as expected.

But, if you are aiming ICS devices, you can go ahead. IMHO, I would develop this kind of apps with Phonegap if Chrome became the default Android's browser (may be in Android 5?). But, I would recommend native-developping your app.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. For the type of app we are developing, considering quality and performance, we decided to go with native development.